# vis.js network : How do I change node label font color dynamically?

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-network

I'm trying to change a node's label color on click of a node.

My default node label colors are '#cccccc'.

I've tried:

```
network.body.nodes[nodeID].options.font.color = '#ffffff';
```

during a node click event, but it didn't work. All the node labels stay at light gray.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've gotten it to work by adding the following lines of code after the above:

```
network.body.emitter.emit('_dataChanged');
network.redraw();
```

Cheers!